# Echoing details of repeating column values

Tags: php, mysql

In my MySQL table I have a column `name`, and there are various repeating names within the table. If I want to display all other column formation for all the people with name `chris` I can use:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM favorites WHERE name='$name'")
if($info = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
echo {$info['name']}
echo {$info['age']}
echo {$info['address']}
```

But then I want to echo the details of the second `chris`, in the table who could be in any   random row within the table I can't specify that information. Is there a way to accomplish this? Thank you.

Comment: `while ($info = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) { //echo your information out }`

Comment: I'm not sure I understood the question properly, could you make a practical example of what you're trying to achieve? Thanks.

Comment: Well, "thank you" for picking wrong answer :\

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) 
{
            echo $row['name'];
            echo $row['age'];
            echo $row['address'];
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help its starting to get better

Comment: Exact duplicate of this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11720402/echoing-details-of-repeating-column-values/11720464#11720464)

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    echo $row['name'];
    echo $info['age'];
    echo $row['address'];
}
```

Comment: ok they seem to super impose on one another but at least they are both there I think I can figure out the rest thanks for your help.

Comment: you gave the answer first and i think @lanka has copy paste your answer. This is wrong